# Android Emulator does not run my app in react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I get a react native configuration error when I run `react-native run-android`. The command gives this error message:

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I can not solve this. I installed all the dependencies. My emulator is also running but the application does not start.

Answer (score 0):

try set up your Android development environment. config environment variable(like path), sure your android sdk tools (like adb) be find on runtime!

Comment: yes sir I set my environment variables but this not resolve